# Service fabric error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I'm new in Service Fabric. What I want is to deploy MVC project as a SF service. Right now I'm want to test it on Local SF cluster, but an issue happens when application starts. And the biggest problem - I can't see any log or something which will describe an error. One thing that I have is SF explorer, but there is no details about exception. Can anybody explain me where I can find what causes an error?

[image]

Comment: For me it was error in ports. I didn't know that each port should have UNIQUE name for each end point inside manifest

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only start one instance of your MVC Service, to avoid port conflicts.

Debug your application, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-debugging-your-application). (Break on all exceptions.)

Read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#service-fabric-service-hosting) about building services that host MVC. This article also mentions some common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

this error is generic error that means your application doesn't work as it should.
you have 2 options to troubleshoot it. one is to go to the event viewer to see if your application throw any error or the "Service fabric" event viewer has any information on your application (usually it doesn't).
second option is to write your own logs of your application and check them instead.
to find your application folder you need to drill down in the SFX until you get to the instance the application is installed on, you will then see the path for your application.
one issue I had a lot in SF new applications is permissions... SF load all applications by default with "Network Service" which is very low permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Presume you have a stateless services. Basically in your service manifest you specified a number of instances 3 for example. However you have less available node on your cluster. This also applied if you have node placement constraint on services. For example: You have 2 node node for front end in 5 node cluster and you want 3 instances

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception at startup ( most likely you havent wired up the commslistener)  .. Have you debugged it on your dev cluster ?

Service fabric has a hook ( The commslistener) which tells it the service is ready , if this is not set ( or there is a startup exception) it will continue to restart.

Ben